# Why this fingering is written for Ab minor blues scale?

Tags: piano, scales, blues

[image: Minor blues scales fingerings]

Can somebody explain why Ab minor scale starts with 412? I would start with 414. Then the whole scale would be faster because of less space to shift fingers. Am I wrong?

Comment: I have small hands, but I'd personally start the Ab minor blues scale with 21, not 41.

Comment: Please don't post text as an image; it can't be searched, copy/pasted into answers or read by screen-readers. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged/320060#320060

Comment: Related question: [What fingerings are used for the minor and major blues scales?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32109/what-fingerings-are-used-for-the-minor-and-major-blues-scales)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I play it 1 2 3 1 2 3 4. Nothing wrong with thumb on a black key if it doesn't twist your hand to get to or from it. That is one way to play it quickly and smoothly.

With fingerng, there is hardly a 'right or wrong' way. Whatever suits a player is his 'right' way. The point of scales is merely to impress on the mind the notes used in a particular key - or to perform for an exam - or to do for a warm-up. But using *part* of that scale in a piece, chances are you wouldn't use the same fingering as you do for the full scale anyway, as you'd be going somewhere else after several notes, which may well require a fingering change.

EDIT: in answer to the actual question, the thought behind it is that by the time you get to the second/third octave, the 4 on A♭ is part of the pattern, so let's start with it. let's face it, at the end of one octave, it's all that's left - with that fingering!

And, looking at some other fingerings, I don't agree they are the best. Just because it's on the internet doesn't make it credible...

Comment: Would you use 123123 1 if you play it in more octaves?

Comment: Personally, I probably wouldn't play motre than one octave! There's no need, unless it's for an exam! But, if pushed, yes, that's my option. I also prefer it to be called b5 rather than #4. It sort of fits better for blues, whereas, #4 is preferrable for jazz. Don't ask why!

Comment: So why nobody plays C# major scale 123 123 123 123 123? Everyone starts from 2, is it better?

Comment: Or even 1234 1234 1234 123?

Comment: C# major - 231 23412 makes more sense. It makes sense to play white keys using thumb when available.

Comment: And what's point of using thumb on white keys if on black is also possible?

Comment: You've missed the point. Thumbs are shorter, so fit better on white keys, leaving longer fingers to play black keys. But *sometimes* it's not practical, and thumb is needed to play on a black key. Of course it'spossible to play any key with any finger, but using sense and logic usually sorts out which is the best way.

Comment: Ok, if time signature is 4/4 and notes are 16ths, so would you play C# major scale 1234... or 2312...?

Comment: Really can't understand what the time sig. and note value has to do with the fingering. Work out what's best for *you* and use it. It's early days to choose an accepted answer yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94902/discussion-between-prako2-and-tim).

Comment: I'm about to start giving lessons, so perhaps later.

Comment: Ok, see you later

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a right and wrong here.

Does your fingering work for you?  If it does then use it.  It might not work for everyone but that's okay, they can use an alternative that suits them.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Blues scales are tricky when played straight up or down through octaves...this gets more complicated when taking into account the starting note..One often assumes the root as the starting note. I find that you can navigate them all using 1234 over and over or 123 over and over, or some combination of those two maybe with a different starting finger.