# Can anyone give me blues scale fingering numbers for left hand piano?

Tags: piano, scales, fingering

I want blues scale fingerings for left hand piano

Comment: Rather like major and minor scale fingerings, each key will have its own finger pattern. And there are two blues scales as well. Major and minor. So which key in particular? And what have you tried so far? So right now, the question needs a lot of clarification!

Comment: @Aaron - please read my comment on that.

Comment: @Tim Your comment is the reason I'm updating the earlier question (answer, that is). It covers both major and minor blues scales in all keys, including patterns that are common to each key.

Comment: @Aaron - my comment is asking the basic question - why bother? " I've breathed in - what do I need to do next, please?"

Answer (score 0):

The principle I use for the left-hand blues scales is to break each scale into two segments and use one of the finger patterns `4321 31` or `421 321`. The beginning and end of each finger pattern does not necessarily correspond to the beginning and end of the scale. Sometimes it works best to start in the middle of a fingering pattern.

See also the linked question for the complete listing of which fingering pattern I prefer for each scale and how I apply them: [What fingerings are used for the minor and major blues scales?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32109/what-fingerings-are-used-for-the-minor-and-major-blues-scales)